# how can I remove part of a names in one column of a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this

```
v1                                         v2
phenzine.MO.4213121906560.C02.name  2.376140e-05
dnium.bte.MO.02400072107987.E10.name    2.423254e-05
trene.MO.024213121906564.C09.name       2.438986e-05
tilli.MO.550760072207033.F09.name       2.495574e-05
tnolone.MO..614615111406.name           2.511859e-05
```

I want to remove part of the first column which then it will looks like below

```
      v1              v2
    phenzine    2.376140e-05
    dnium.bte   2.423254e-05
    trene       2.438986e-05
    tilli       2.495574e-05
    tnolone     2.511859e-05
```

I know I must use grep or sub but I could not do it

Comment: Do you have `MO` common for all the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below regex if 'MO' is common for all the elements

```
 df1$v1 <- sub('\\.MO.*', '', df1$v1)
```

Suppose, you want to remove the strings from `.` followed by first capital letter

```
 sub('\\.[A-Z].*', '', df1$v1)
 #[1] "phenzine"  "dnium.bte" "trene"     "tilli"     "tnolone"
```

Or if it is more specific

```
sub('\\.(MO|NO|NR).*', '', df1$v1)
#[1] "phenzine"  "dnium.bte" "trene"     "tilli"     "tnolone"
```

Comment: I have .MO. or .NO. or .NR. one of these three is common

Comment: @Nemo I updated the solution.  Please check if that works in your original dataset.

Comment: thanks, can you also please tell me how to remove the point . which appears sometimes in the middle of the name like dnium.bte ? it become like dnium bte

Comment: @Nemo You can do another `sub` on the previous result. ie. `sub('[.]', ' ', df1$v1)`

Comment: when I do that sub('[.]', ' ', df1$v1) it brings them together like dnium.bte to dniumbte

Comment: @Nemo I meant `' '`, so that the `.` will be replaced by a space.  In the code you showed, it is replaced by `''`

Comment: OMG, I got it, thanks. it is complicated, I am never gona learn how to use grep or sub :-(

Comment: @Nemo Please don't give up without trying.  It is actually fun to learn `gsub`.  Just try some strings and do all those replacements for fun.  By trial and error you will learn it quickly.